# xsd documentation

Tags: xml, xsd

I have one xsd file ,I used xmlpad to validate this xsd against xml files. xmlpad will generate documentation for xsd. but my problem is I added some xml comments in the xsd file (for documentation purpose). when i generate documentation for xsd using xmlpad comments are not appeared in the documentation.Can any one suggest me how to overcome this problem and also is there any other way to do this? any other free tools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [`xsd:annotation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256102.aspx) to document your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I used XMLSPY. If you include the explanation with xsd:annotation tag. It will serve as documentation. I hope you can do the same in XMLPAD.